# Custom type attribute on <script> tag - valid html?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

On the site I work on, we're using `<script>` tags with a `src` attribute but with a custom `type` (let's call it `type="text/x-custom"`).  The scripts are javascript, but the idea is we only want them to run after certain conditions have been met.  We have another piece of javascript which checks for these conditions, and when met, changes the type to `text/javascript` and causes them to run.  The problem is, running the page through https://validator.w3.org/nu/ gives errors:

*A script element with a src attribute must not have a type attribute whose value is anything other than the empty string, a JavaScript MIME type, or module.*

Is there anything I can do to make these errors go away, or should I just ignore them?

Comment: You can consider creating `<script>` tag dynamically. Is this an option?
The other option is to set `src` attribute, not the `type`.

Comment: You could also create a custom attr, like `data-type`, that you can use in the javascript that checks for the conditions.

Comment: @benjaminknox Thanks, but unless I make the actual `type` something other than `text/javascript`, the scripts will run immediately, which we don't want.

Comment: hmm, well, you could also use a different media type like this `text/example`, here is a list of acceptable media types: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text

That seems weird to me though.

Another option could be to put the javascript in a custom element that is hidden on the page and check for that element in the conditions.